# Python - get call arguments unevaluated

Tags: python

Is there any way, in Python, of accessing the unevaluated call arguments from a function? I'm basically trying to do the equivalent of R's deparse(substitute(x)):

```
def test(x):
    print(deparse(substitute(x)))

test(2*3)
```

Which would print:
'2*3'

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking can you give a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Not unless you introspect on the source code itself. The expression is fully evaluated before `test` sees the value of `x`.

Comment: You could pass the argument as a string, and `eval()` it within `test()`. Otherwise, no: x receives `6`.